# Contractor Tax Rates [UK]

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom

I worked for 6 months last year as a contractor for a company straight out of university in the UK.  I wasn't having to pay taxes with my paycheck but I know I must pay them at the end of the year.  Can anyone tell me how much I have to pay?  I was getting ~£3500 a month salary and about another £1000 for expenses.  My parents tell me the tax rate is 25% but is that on all of it or just the salary part?

I don't think this will affect this but I was unemployed before working this and I now work as staff (with tax included in the paycheck) for the same company from the start of November.

Comment: Who did the paychecks go to, you or a Limited Company you own? Also was the 6 months contracting period May 2019-October 2019 inclusive? The tax year(s) they fall into is relevant to how much tax you'd pay. For the expenses, is that money you actually spent related to your job and do you have receipts for it?

Comment: Paychecks went to me.  May to October inclusive.  Expenses are travel, accommodation, subsistence and are paid as a flat amount per day and aren't directly related to my job.  I probably have receipts for travel and accommodation but not subsistence.

Comment: Did you have a normal place of work and were the expenses for travelling/living/subsistence when working at that normal place of work? (If so they're probably taxable, but if you had to travel around for work they are probably not).

Comment: Also, in your employment, what's the tax code on your payslip, and does your "taxable pay year to date" or similar include any of your contracting earnings? (This will probably have been determined by the answers you gave when they went through their new starter checklist with you)